# removing blank rows from a table using office js

Tags: office-js, office-addins, word-addins, word-web-addins

I'm developing a Word Add-in (Word API + Office.js) where i am working with content controls, I am trying to read the table content inside a content control where I need remove the empty rows 
Sample:
I have this table inside a content control I have to remove the blank rows

[image]

I tried the below code to read the table content but getting undefined error at reading table

```
   function checktable() {
    Word.run(function (context) {
        // Queue a command to get the current selection and then
        // create a proxy range object with the results.
        var contentControls = context.document.contentControls.getByTag('control').getFirst();       
        context.load(contentControls,'tables');

        return context.sync()
            .then(function () {
                var table;
                // Get the longest word from the selection.
                if (contentControls.tables.items.length === 0) {
                    document.getElementById('lblstatus').innerText += "No Tables found";
                }
                else {
                    document.getElementById('lblstatus').innerText += " Tables found";
                    table = contentControls.tables.getFirstOrNullObject();

                }

                context.load(table, 'values');


            })
            .then(context.sync)
            .then(function () {

                var Tablevaules = table.values;


                // Queue a command to highlight the search results.
                document.getElementById('lblstatus').innerText += element + ":" + "Successs";

            });
    })
        .catch(errorHandler);
}
```

Please let me know whether any other way to achieve this functionality or is it possible using office js

Answer (score 0):

I think I see three problems in your code:

1. The var you are calling `contentControls` is actually a single content control. (The first one with the tag "control".) The plural name is confusing and makes your code hard to parse.
2. The following line in your code has a problem:

   ```
   context.load(contentControls,'tables');
   ```

   The `tables` property is a collection property. You can't load collection properties. You need to load the property (or properties) of the members of the collection; that is, the tables in the tables.items array. It looks like you need to load the `length` property, since that is the one that your code reads after the sync. I recommend the book [Building Office Add-ins](http://buildingofficeaddins.com), especially the section **Loading Collections** for more information.
3. When you use an `*OrNullObject` method, you need to call a `context.sync` and then test the object to see if it's null. See [orNullObject Methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/excel/excel-add-ins-advanced-concepts#ornullobject-methods).